# Unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Wampserver 3.2 on Windows 10.
PHP 7.3.12 MYSQL 5.7.28

While I'm trying to `php artisan migrate`

I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel'`

But I'm sure that the database 'laravel' is definitely exist.

I also checked the settings of databases in my .env file and it's all correct.

Strangely, I replace laravel to mysql, which is default created while installing MySQL.

`php artisan migrate` worked properly.

Can anyone help?

this is my database:

[image]

this is my .env file:

[image]

Comment: When you change the values on `.env` file you need to rerun `php artisan serve`

Comment: Check your database name in mysql server

Comment: @Dmitry database name is correct.

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand I already do that

Comment: @Karamalz Could you provide image with databases?

Comment: @Dmitry I update my question.

Comment: @Karamalz Could you provide .env here?

Comment: update in my question

Comment: Close your server then run ```php artisan config:cache``` . Again run serve, I hope work it.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun not working..QQ

Comment: Do you run your mySql server?

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun Yes, of course!

Comment: Try this ```php artisan config:clear```

Comment: @Karamalz you can try recreate your database or try another one.

Comment: @Dmitry I rebuild my whole environment, then it's ok now... thanks for helping